# execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.TypeException: Invalid id value for this SObject type:

Tags: apex

I am trying to create orderitems from OpportunityLine items and also creating order on Opportunity. But I am getting the following error

> Error: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.TypeException:
>   Invalid id value for this SObject type: 00kq0000008mWXjAAM:
>   Class.Autocreation .CreatingOrders:
>
> at this particular line [ordr1.Id = oli.Id;]

Which Id needs to be take, I don't understand Can anyone help me.Thanks in advance

```
public class Autocreation {

    public static void CreatingOrders(List<Opportunity> newlist){
          set<Id> oppId = new set<Id>();
        for(Opportunity opp : newList){
            oppId.add(opp.id); //Adding Opportunity's to Set.    
             }
        List<Opportunity> oppList = [select id,name,StageName,Accountid, (select Status,Account.name,enddate from Orders)
                                     from Opportunity where Id =: oppId];

         List<OpportunityLineItem> oppList1 = [SELECT id,Quantity,Product2Id,
                                      UnitPrice,Description, TotalPrice,PricebookEntry.Name, PricebookEntry.Product2.Family,
                                      OpportunityId FROM OpportunityLineItem where OpportunityId =: oppId];



        List<Order> insrtordrs = new List<Order>();
        List<OrderItem> insrtordrs1 = new List<OrderItem>();

        for(Opportunity opp1 : oppList){
            for(OpportunityLineItem oli : oppList1 ){  
            if (opp1.Orders.size()>0){
                system.debug('Orders exists*******************' +opp1.Orders);

            } 
            else if(opp1.StageName == 'Closed-Won') {
              Order ordr =new Order();
              ordr.AccountId = opp1.AccountId;
              ordr.OpportunityId = opp1.id;
              ordr.Status = 'Draft';
              ordr.EffectiveDate = system.today();
              //ordr.ContractId = opp1.ContractId; 
              insrtordrs .add(ordr);

                OrderItem ordr1 =new OrderItem();
                ordr1.Id = oli.Id;
                ordr1.PricebookEntryId = oli.PricebookEntryId;
                ordr1.UnitPrice        = oli.UnitPrice;
                ordr1.Description      = oli.Description;
                ordr1.Quantity         = oli.Quantity;
                insrtordrs1 .add(ordr1);  

            }   
           }
        }
        insert insrtordrs ;
        insert insrtordrs1 ;

     }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Id is a system generated field .We need to assign the order id with the new line item id.
As i understood  there id no relationship between Order item and oppoutunity item.
Try assigning  below and check
Ordr1.id=Ordr.id .

Comment: You cannot perform an `insert` DML with the `Id` field populated *at all*.

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant to assign the `OrderId` field, not the `Id` field. You cannot `insert` records that have the Id field populated, and assigning the Id of an `OpportunityLineItem` to the `Id` field of an `OrderItem` isn't an operation that makes sense. There's no relationship between an `OrderItem` and an `OpportunityLineItem`.

Where you have

```
ordr1.Id = oli.Id;
```

you probably wanted to populate `order1.OrderId` with the `Id` of `ordr`. However, `ordr` hasn't been inserted yet, so it doesn't *have* an `Id`.

If you don't want to mess around with External Ids (I usually don't) to insert parent and child objects in a single operation, I would instead of a `List<Order>` and `List<OrderItem>`, build `Map<Id, Order>` and `Map<Id, List<OrderItem>>` collections, which are keyed with the Opportunity's Id. That will allow you to insert the Orders first, and then correlate the Order Items to their assigned Orders using the common Opportunity Id.

Build your Orders and Order Items and populate those data structures, then do `insert orderMap.values()` to insert your Orders. Finally, iterate over the Opportunity Ids to link the Order Items to their Orders and insert them:

```
List<OrderItem> finalOrderItems = new List<OrderItem>();
for (Id oppId : orderMap.keySet()) {
    for (OrderItem oi : orderItemMap.get(oppId)) {
        oi.OrderId = orderMap.get(oppId).Id;
        finalOrderItems.add(oi);
    }
}
insert finalOrderItems;
```